# Загрузка JS скриптов

Tags: javascript, json

На странице есть кнопка и скрипт который ее обрабатывает

```html
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.but', function(){
    alert("текст"); 
  });   
</script> 
<button type="submit" class="but">кнопка</button>
```

Если находится скрипт с кнопкой на одной странице то работает. Если вывести скрипт в отдельный файл, который потом на странице с кнопкой подключить, то не работает. Как это исправить?

Comment: @splash58 в начале, но сам факт, что я пытаюсь подключить скрипт в своей CMS там не работает так, на отдельной странице от сайта работает при любом подключении

Comment: @splash58 все решил, в одном из подключаемых файлов с формой был скрипт **$(document).ready(function(){** его нужно было вынести в общие скрипты вначале, и все заработало=)

Comment: ну что ж, отлично !

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать подобный синтаксис:

file.js

```
(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.but', function(){
      alert("текст"); 
    });   
 }());
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```